# Can't load static files in my django project, error 404

Tags: django

I'm new to Django and i've seen a lot of people asking about this particular problem but i followed every instruction i could find and it still doesn't work.

My directorys look like this:

```
/Peperina
  /Writing
    /statics/writing
               /css
               /scss
               /js
                  forms.js
    /templates/writing
        forms.html
```

---

my setings.py:

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

(...)

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'writing.apps.WritingConfig',
]

(...)

STATICFILES_FINDERS = [ 
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder', 
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder', 
] 

STATIC_URL = '/statics/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'statics'),
)

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
```

---

My urls.py:

```
(...)
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

---

finaly my forms.html

```
(...)
{% load static %}
    <script src="{% static 'writing\js\forms.js' %}"></script>
```

---

yet 404 keeps showing up

Comment: Why does your directory `/Writing` has a capital letter ?

Comment: actually thats a typo in my post, my code doesnt have a capital letter

Comment: Is DEBUG set to True/False? How do you serve: Runserver or Apache or ..  ? If Apache please post your host or virtual host definition. Do you see static files in BASE_DIR/staticfiles/ ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your `STATIC_ROOT` to `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'statics')` ?

Answer (score 0):

I have had this same problem multiple times myself.

I'd first start by removing the "writing" directory, and move all folders up.

You won't need to change your settings.py file too much if you start by doing that.

Create a new directory, called "static_root" in the same level as your current "statics" folder and copy all the static files you've got in your statics folder over to there. Be sure to have two copies of each (one in "statics" and another in "static_root"). This will be explained shortly.

Your static file information in settings.py should now be changed to look like this:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'statics')
STATIC_URL = '/statics/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_root'),
)
```

The reason you need to have a separate static_root is because Django sometimes gets a bit funny about there being a root static folder and a normal static folder. More info can be found [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/).

I personally do not have STATICFILES_FINDERS in my settings.py, so test with removing that.

Maybe also try running `Python manage.py collectstatic` as this will collect the static files for you.

If none of this works, as you mention you are new to Django, I'd recommend following some tutorials from start to finish to see if you can get it to work.
E.g. [start here if you haven't done already.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/intro/tutorial01/)

Comment: well, maybe I should have said that in my question, but actually in addition to my app 'writing' I have another app 'users'. So the 'writing' directory is there to identify each 'statics' folders

Comment: Glad you found the answer! Do try to include all information you can in your questions so that people can help you out more easily.

Answer (score 0):

Well this turned up to be a pretty goofy solution but i changed the name of all my "statics" directorys to just "static" and then did the same thing in my settings and... it worked
So... thanks anyway